# flatbuffers: serializing/deseializing a struct with desired size

Tags: c++, struct, flatbuffers

I try to serialize a basic struct with flatbuffers on C++ such as:

```
struct Vec3 {
  x:float;
  y:float;
  z:float;
}
```

with the code below:

```
Vec3 my_pos = {1.1, 1.2, 1.3};
auto myOtherItemn = myBuilder.CreateStruct<Vec3>(position);
myBuilder.Finish(myOtherItemn);
```

Now when i display the size of my pos:

```
printf("size of Vec3           : %d\n", sizeof(MyGame::Sample::Vec3));
```

the size is **12**, as expected. size of float is 4 bytes.

but after serialization the serialized object size is:

```
printf("size of serialized data: %d\n", myBuilder.GetSize());
```

is **16**

when i check there is a 4 byte at the begging of the serialized data. I am not happy with this additional 4 bytes. I want to get rid of it.

So is there a way to have a serialized output with the same size as original struct size (namely 12 for this case)?

Comment: Quoting from the [Flatbuffer internals page](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_internals.html): "The format starts with an `uoffset_t` to the root object in the buffer."

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't have a `struct` as the root of a buffer, it needs to be a `table`. `CreateStruct` is a special case function for use with unions, please follow the tutorial on how to serialize structs.

Also, FlatBuffers is a format that has additional management data beyond the actual data you store. You cannot get the size down to just the bytes of the actual data. If this is what you want, you'd need to hard-code your own format and just write structs to disk directly.